# Getting the dictionary with the most recent date from an array of dictionaries

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdate, nsdictionary

I have an array of dictionaries. These dictionaries have a format like this:

```
NSDictionary *oneDict = @{
              @"code": @"123"
              @"name": @"car"
              @"date": creationDate
}
```

these dictionaries are stored in a NSArray.

I need to extract the dictionary with the most recent date from that array.

I can discover the most recent date by doing this:

```
NSArray *extractDates = [array objectForKey:@"date"];
NSArray sortedDates = [extractDates sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
NSDate *mostRecentDate = (NSDate *)[sortedDates lastObject];
```

Now I know, I can interact over the array and look for that date, so I can get the dictionary, but I wonder if Objective-C has some sort of mechanism that can do that directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                                     sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" 
                                                 ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dateDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [array
         sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)[sortedArray lastObject];
```

Comment: I think you misread my question. Thanks for the code but once I have the most recent date, I want to extract the dictionary from the array that has this date. :)

Comment: ahhh, I was not getting the whole picture. I thought you were sorting the array of dates. You are sorting the array of dicts!!! Very good. Thanks.